# How to make a filter to check if someone has tagged a user with @?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am making a social networking site. I am wondering how to make a jinja filter in python to make any word that starts with @ a link to their profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Jinja filter you can use:

```
from flask import Markup

def linkify(text):
    return Markup(re.sub(r'@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', r'<a href="/\1">@\1</a>', text))
```

It finds usernames starting with `@`, containing lowercase or uppercase letters, numbers and underscores. It replaces it a link to the profile (`\1` represents their username without the `@`)

Here's how you'd add it to you're environment:

```
 app.jinja_env.filters['linkify'] = linkify
```

And call it from a Jinja template:

```
{{ post|linkify }}
```

**EDIT**

Run this in a Python shell:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'This is a post mentioning @nathancahill and @jacob_bennet'
>>> re.sub(r'@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', r'<a href="/\1">@\1</a>', text)
'This is a post mentioning <a href="/nathancahill">@nathancahill</a> and <a href="/jacob_bennet">@jacob_bennet</a>'
```

Do you get the same output?

Comment: It won't create a link. It just creates text.

Comment: See my edit where it works for me, not sure what you're doing differently.

Comment: Jinja is just putting the html as text instead of actually making a link.

Comment: There is a built-in `urlize` filter that turns urls into clickable links. If the above answer does not work -- I didn't try it -- then the source for `urlize` should show you what to do. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.urlize

Comment: Looking at [the `urlize` source](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/ab7840328f3c6303b4509972f7751e9ab1ee36c7/src/jinja2/utils.py#L287) I see that they start with manual escaping via `str(markupsafe.escape(text))` but I don't see where they eventually mark the result as "safe". And if the result is never marked as safe, and autoescaping is enabled, then you'll end up with the "html as text" the OP mentions, but `urlize` works :shrug: